# How do i access something from my Angular 2 component after i am already "in" my Kendo Grid

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, components, kendo-grid

So, what is happening is that after I create a new row in my grid, I need to access to other information within my component. I would normally access these using "this.method" or "this.property", however, after I have created this new row, "this" no longer refers to the component, but instead, it refers to the grid. I have multiple reasons to "break out" of the grid and access my component, but cannot figure out how.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my',
  templateUrl: 
    <kendo-grid 
        id="myGrid" 
        [kendoGridBinding]="postingGridData" 
        [kendoGridTemplateEditing]="addNewPost" 
        (save)="saveHandler($event)"
        (remove)="removeHandler($event)">
            <ng-template kendoGridToolbarTemplate>enter code here
                <button kendoGridAddCommand id="addNewPost">Add new</button>
            </ng-template>
    </kendo-grid>
})
export class MyComponent{
    // random property to access
    public num: number;
    // create new grid row
    addNewPost(): void{
        let thisNumber = this.num;
        this.doThisMethod();
    }
    // another method on the component
    doThisMethod(): void{
        doSomething
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close. You need to define you **addHandler** for the Kendo Grid. Once you do that you will have access to *this* inside the **doThisMethod**.

I created a [Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mltghm?file=app/app.component.ts). It's a mashup of your code and the the Kendo documentation for the [CommandColumnComponent](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/editing/custom-reactive-editing/). When you run the Stackblitz you will see how the component can access the **this.num** property inside the **doThisMethod** function. [This](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/editing/custom-reactive-editing/) page may also help you out. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

So what was happening is that when you have [kendoGridTemplateEditing] in your grid, it auto-magically handles the add/cancel/delete/edit functionality for you, so when inside a one of its functions, "this" now refers to that directive. The work around for this is binding "this" to the method in the constructor.

```
constructor() {
    this.addNewPost= this.addNewPost.bind(this);
}
```